# Proof that $\{\,\left]a,\infty\right [\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\,\}\cup\{\mathbb{R} \}\cup\{\emptyset \}$ is topology of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Proof that $\mathcal{T}:=\{\,\left]a,\infty\right [\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\,\}\cup\{\mathbb{R} \}\cup\{\emptyset \}$ is topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

I have slight trouble on writing this down.. I'll first write what I have now.

Obviously $\mathbb{R},\emptyset\in\mathcal{T}$.

Let $U_{i}\in\mathcal{T}$ $(i\in I)$.

Let $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}U_{i}$.  If the union is empty or $\mathbb{R}$, then we are done, otherwise there exists infimum.

Let $a:=\inf\{a_{i}\mid i\in I \}$, $a_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, $\bigcup_{i\in I}=]a,\infty[$, and $\bigcup_{i\in I}\in\mathcal{T}$.

Finally let $U_{1},\ldots ,U_{n}\in\mathcal{T}$.

Then there is $a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $U_{i}=]a_{i},\infty[$ by all $i=1,\ldots , n$. Now, $\bigcap_{i\in I}^{n}U_{i}=\bigcap_{i\in I}^{n}]a_{i},\infty[$ and then $\bigcap_{i\in I}^{n}U_{i}\in\mathcal{T}$.

Fixed.

Also, what is the name of this particular topology so I can refer to it with it's correct name?

Comment: That's not a proof at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe your proof is quite right. How exactly do you get from $(U_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathcal{T}$ to the fact that $\cup_{i\in I} U_i$ is of the form $]a,\infty[$?

I would do it along the following lines: Suppose $U_i\in\mathcal{T}$ for all $i\in I$, where $I$ is arbitrary. Let $a=\inf\left\{ \cup_{i\in I} U_i\right\}$, and prove that $\cup_{i\in I} U_i = ]a,\infty[$. Then $\cup_{i\in I} U_i\in\mathcal{T}$.

Similarly, you need to prove that if $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{T}$, then $U_1\cap U_2$ has the form $]a,\infty[$: If $U_1=]a_1,\infty[$ and $U_2=]a_2,\infty[$, then $U_1\cap U_2 = ]a,\infty[$, where $a=\max\{a_1,a_2\}$.

Comment: For the union part, I'd suggest a case distinction: If the union is empty or all of $\Bbb R$ we are done. Only in the remaining case, the inf exist is a real number) and then ...

Comment: Is there a name for this type of topology?

Comment: @Zzz It is called the right-order-topology on the real line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Left_and_right_order_topologies